# How to convert pixels to cm in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pixel

I'm writing CSS for project and need to convert pixel to centimeter with JavaScript. how do I calculate this conversion?

Answer (score 6):

You could use window.devicePixelRatio to check for device caps. It is used in most browsers.

Answer (score 2):

> There are 2.54 centimeters per inch; if it is sufficient to assume 96 pixels per inch, the formula is rather simple:
>
> centimeters = pixels * 2.54 / 96
>
> There is a way to get the configured pixels per inch of your display for Microsoft Windows called GetDeviceCaps. Microsoft has a guide called "Developing DPI-Aware Applications", look for the section "Creating DPI-Aware Fonts".

[sample code](https://gist.github.com/comficker/2b97446cd968a00d75486564e5d056f5)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to convert the pixels to cm using javascript, you can use following formula:

`1px = 0.026458 cm;`

Please take care this is only for conversion of px to cm.

I am not aware if you are taking `DPI` of screen into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

On modern devices it is sufficient to take into account the actual `window.devicePixelRatio`:

```
function px2cm(px) {
  var n = 0;
  var cpi = 2.54; // centimeters per inch
  var dpi = 96; // dots per inch
  var ppd = window.devicePixelRatio; // pixels per dot
  return (px * cpi / (dpi * ppd)).toFixed(n);
}
```